# Adjacent cells in QuadTree

Tags: algorithm, quadtree

Is there any way to find adjacent cells in a quadtree subdivision? I mean all the cell adjacent to the selected one at any level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space filling curves fills a space completley and reduces the 2 dimension to 1 dimension. I've written a free php class at phpclasses.org (hilbert curve). It includes a z curve, 4 hilbert curves and the moore curve and a quadkey function. Here is a blog about collision detection and quadtrees: lab.polygonal.de/?p=202?

[image]

A morton a.k.a. z-curve is easy to construct. Translate the x-and y-value to binary and concatenate the values. You can find some code here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. You can verify the upper boundaries  by using the most significant bits.

Comment: Thanks Chibox, anything more detailed from the programming point of view?

Comment: I still find difficult to see the connection between my question and z-curves.

Comment: No luck. I need to find the cells adjacent to the selected one even at many level of distance and I don't understand how z-curves could help, sorry.

Comment: Finally I found an image that explain your concept, thanks. http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC96238.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of which child the node is. If the adjacent node is in the same parent, just return it. If not, you need to walk upward in the tree until you can find a common ancestor. Then follow a similar path downwards until you come back to the correct level (or reach the bottom).

```cs
Node WalkLeft(Node node)
{
    if (node == null) return null;

    Node leftParent;
    switch (node.ChildDirection)
    {
        case ChildDirection.Root:
            return null;
        case ChildDirection.TopRight:
            return node.Parent.TopLeft;
        case ChildDirection.BottomRight:
            return node.Parent.BottomLeft;
        case ChildDirection.TopLeft:
            leftParent = WalkLeft(node.Parent);
            return leftParent.TopRight ?? leftParent;
        case ChildDirection.BottomLeft:
            leftParent = WalkLeft(node.Parent);
            return leftParent.BottomLeft ?? leftParent;
    }
}
```

Similarly for the other directions.

`x ?? y` picks the first non-null value.

Comment: If we're using Morton ordering (see the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756071/2799848)) then your entire `switch` statement can be rewritten as a single operation to get the binary complement of the low-order bits. This interpretation scales a whole let better for higher dimensions as well (e.g. otherwise oct-trees for 3D would have 8 different walk functions with 8+1 case statements in each `switch`): `(1 << this.Dim) - idx - 1` (I took this subtraction approach over the bitshifting madness needed to only complement the lower bits).